# How can I create a default value for a binding in Xamarin using BindableProperty.Create?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a template to make a label:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Grid Padding="20,0" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test;assembly=Test" 
      x:Class="Test.MyTemplate" 
      x:Name="this" >
    <Label Grid.Column="1" 
           IsVisible="{Binding LabelVisible, Source={x:Reference this}}"
           Text="Test" />
</Grid>
```

and

```
public partial class MyTemplate : Grid
{

    public event EventHandler Action;

    public MyTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty LabelVisibleProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(LabelVisible),
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(MyTemplate),
            true); // << I set this to true as I think it is for the default setting

    public bool LabelVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(LabelVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelVisibleProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

I would like this to default to a value of true if I code this in the page:

```
<template:MyTemplate />
```

But my label remains invisible even though is set the last property of BindableProperty.Create to true (I think this is where I set the default).

Am I not setting the default correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the UI doesn't get notified that `LabelVisible` is updated and it doesn't update `IsVisible` accordingly. Either implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, or add the `propertyChanged` parameter to your `BindableProperty.Create` call.

The latter can be done like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty LabelVisibleProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(LabelVisible),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DataGridTemplate),
        true, onPropertyChanged: OnLabelVisiblePropertyChanged);
```

And implement a method like this:

```
private static void OnLabelVisiblePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if (bindable != null && bindable is DataGridTemplate template)
        template.MyLabel.IsVisible = (bool)newValue;
}
```

You would have to give your `Label` a `x:Name` value and the binding doesn't really do much anymore at that point: `<Label x:Name="MyLabel" Grid.Column="1" Text="Test" />`

Comment: Can you give me an example of how i could implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  Sorry I don't understand how i can do that.  Would that be better or just the same as the method you suggested.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you do one or the other. You could try this way, for the `INotifyPropertyChanged` I would have to check what is needed. But it will take some time :)

Comment: Also something that seems odd is that your class is called `MyTemplate` but in your `BindableProperty.Create` you mention `DataGridTemplate` as declaring type. Why is that?